# Can “such as” be used in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> Teenagers like to patronize Internet cafes, which may cause many problems, such as staying out too late and then just skipping school.

Can “such as” be used in this sentence? If not, could you please tell me how to make it correct?

Comment: Yes, _such as_ can be used in many contexts where a category is mentioned (problems) and then some examples of things in that category are listed.

Comment: @KateBunting sounds like an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, *such as* is perfectly correct in this sentence. It can be used in many contexts where a category is mentioned (problems) and then some examples of things in that category are listed.